# Connecting to a shared internet connection in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, virtualbox, internet

I have managed to set up my iPhone as a wireless network adapter within my Windows 7 virtual machine which is running within Ubuntu. Is there a way for Ubuntu to use the shared internet connection from the VirtualBox machine?

In order to clarify:

[Internet]--[Router]-Wireless-[iPhone]-USB-[Virtual Machine inside Ubuntu]

I can't access the internet provided by the iPhone in Ubuntu directily because the OS needs to have a modem driver installed in order to connect with the iPhone. So the obvious solution to me would be to use ICS in Windows (aka the Virtual Machine) to share the internet with the parent OS (Ubuntu in this cawse). Is this possible? If so, how would I go about connecting to the shared connection?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/45112/is-it-possible-to-use-windows-internet-connection-inside-virtual-box-installaion

Comment: did you try `libimobiledevice` or other solutions like this one http://techie-buzz.com/foss/getting-iphone-internet-tethering-working-in-linux.html

Comment: @user827992 how would i go about getting libimobiledevice if I don't have internet access for Ubuntu?

Comment: @Mitch This is not dup. He wants to use guest os network to host (not host's connection to guest)

Comment: and @Mitch I did read that question you linked to but I have a significantly different situation, correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Web-E: but this was asked before too (don't know if solved however).

Comment: @Takkat if it was asked before, do you think you could provide the link? That'd be really helpful if you could!

Comment: @user827992 I looked over the techie-buzz article and think it work great if I had internet access for my PC :(

Comment: @RafLance if you have make and all the build-tools already installed in your system you just have to download the source code and you can do that from anywhere and transfer this source on your pc with an USB pen or something like that.

Comment: @RafLance: did not find it. At least not an answered one. You may need a software router for Windows. Can't test this however.

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 4+ years and cannot reply to comments on this unanswered question 5+ years old which would pertain to an EOL version of Ubuntu. VTC as `not reproducible`.